# How to apply a logical operation to all expressions in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of expressions and I need to apply AND on all the items.

Input: `{xP == 1+x , yP == 3+y}`

Desired output:    `xP == 1+x && yP == 3+y`

I tried the following but it does not work.

```
Replace[{xp==1 + x , yp==3 + y}, "," -> "&&"]
```

Comment: `And @@ {xP == 1 + x, yP == 3 + y}` . From the docs, look up `Apply`.

Comment: @Syed thanks that's right

Comment: Just for fun `Distribute[{xP == 1+x , yP == 3+y}, List,List,Sequence,And]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `And @@ {xP == 1 + x, yP == 3 + y}` which is short for `Apply[And, {xP == 1 + x, yP == 3 + y}]`

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
Reduce[{xP == 1 + x, yP == 3 + y}, {xP, yP}]
(*xP == 1 + x && yP == 3 + y*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
And @@ {xP == 1 + x, yP == 3 + y} 
xP == 1 + x && yP == 3 + y
```